# How to make Golang google Maps SDK NearbySearch returns search results from multiple pages

Tags: google-maps, go

I am trying to use Golang version of Google Maps API (https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-go.git) to do NearbySearch. I have configured the requests with geolocation, type, radius and try to use the first page token returned from the first response, then include the token in the second request to get the results on second page. So on and so forth.

Is my understanding correct? When I tried the above method, the API returns "invalid request". Below is the code snippet.

```
token := ""
for i:=0; i < 3; i++{
    req := &maps.NearbySearchRequest{
    Location: &latlng,
    Radius: 1000,
    Type: "restaurant",
    PageToken:token,
    }

    res, err := client.NearbySearch(context.Background(), req)
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Got %d results on this page \n", len(res.Results))
    fmt.Printf("Next page token is %s \n", res.NextPageToken)

    token = res.NextPageToken
}
```

Comment: You may need to delay between pages

Comment: You mean I should add sleep function between each iteration?

Comment: That might work..

Comment: 50% latency is around 350ms. After setting 2000 ms, it works consistently. I guess this is a hyper-parameter I need to tune based on google's service. Need to log this.